# Can the number of sleeping task in the current window be shown in Tmux statusbar?

Tags: background-process, tmux

I often use `^Z` to make sleep a process, possibly open a new one, make this one sleep too, and so on, also moving between different Tmux windows.

So what I would like, is that the Tmux status bar update relevantly to indicate me how many processes are sleeping in the currently focused window.

Is that possible?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: Currently bash, but I'm planning to move to fish, and still use zsh here and there. So I would preferably want to find a portable solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common question - how to pass information from a shell inside tmux to tmux. The easiest way to do this is to have your shell do it as part of `PS1` or some other variable that is evaluated when the prompt is printed.

There are two things you can do:

1) Set a user option with `tmux set -w @myoption xyz`, then you can use it in the status line with `#{@myoption}`. This has the disadvantage that it cannot work over ssh.

2) Set the pane title using the escape sequence, for example: `printf "\033]2;xyz\033\\"`. It is then available in `#{pane_title}`. This works over ssh but had the disadvantage that there is no way to prevent applications also changing the title if they want.

In either case you will only want to run this when `TMUX` is set, so something like:

```
[ -n "$TMUX" ] && tmux set -w @myoption $(jobs|wc -l)
```